# What VBA code can give screen coordinates of left,top of a page of an MS word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

What code to write for Word Macro to get the coordinates of left, top corner of a page of a word document?

The Left and Top properties of the Page object are always zero, so I cannot use them.

I need screen coordinates of the left, top corner of a page in a word document.

How to get that?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work for the page, but it'll give you the coordinates of the top and left of the active window. Is that of any help? (Or does it get you any closer?)

```
Public Sub WindowPosition()

  Dim leftCoord As Long
  Dim topCoord As Long
  Dim w As Long
  Dim h As Long

  ActiveWindow.GetPoint leftCoord, topCoord, w, h, ActiveDocument

  Debug.Print "Position:" & leftCoord & ":" & topCoord

End Sub
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172241%28v=office.11%29.aspx

NB: [Looks like](http://shaunakelly.com/word/word-development/selecting-or-referring-to-a-page-in-the-word-object-model.html) working with pages is out of the question with the Word object model.

Comment: Thank you. I need to write VBA code to draw a line at the current mouse position. But for that I need to know the coordinates of the mouse with respect to the current page. I can get screen coordinates of the mouse using API. If I can somehow get screen coordinates of the top, left of the page, then I can subtract to find coordinates of mouse with respect to the page. So not sure if left,top of ActiveWindow will help. Anyway, I am checking.